# Selenium webdriver not using selected profile (user-data-dir)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to using Selenium & Webdriver, but from what I've been able to read, I should be able to start the webdriver using an existing chrome profile. I am doing this so that I can make use of the profile's chrome extensions & saved accounts. I have been attempting to do so using the below Python snippet inside of a jupyter notebook.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 2/")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

print(driver.capabilities)
```

Upon executing the cell, a new chrome window pops up as expected with the appropriate web page, but the window does not have my specified profile. It instead shows "Person 1", and appears to be a blank profile from what I can tell.

No errors are thrown, and the print statement returns the following information:

```
{'acceptInsecureCerts': False, 'browserName': 'chrome', 'browserVersion': '96.0.4664.110', 'chrome': {'chromedriverVersion': '96.0.4664.45 (76e4c1bb2ab4671b8beba3444e61c0f17584b2fc-refs/branch-heads/4664@{#947})', 'userDataDir': '/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 2/'}, 'goog:chromeOptions': {'debuggerAddress': 'localhost:59309'}, 'networkConnectionEnabled': False, 'pageLoadStrategy': 'normal', 'platformName': 'mac os x', 'proxy': {}, 'setWindowRect': True, 'strictFileInteractability': False, 'timeouts': {'implicit': 0, 'pageLoad': 300000, 'script': 30000}, 'unhandledPromptBehavior': 'dismiss and notify', 'webauthn:extension:credBlob': True, 'webauthn:extension:largeBlob': True, 'webauthn:virtualAuthenticators': True}
```

It shows the correct path to the `userDataDir` I want, yet the window does not match. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, so any help or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it a default blank profile? When you do something on Profile 1, does the history show up in Profile 2?

Comment: It was blank, but you're right, when I do things in the new profile they are visible in the `userDataDir`. So I am able to reinstall the extensions I need & sign into accounts now and they should remain with this profile. I appreciate the help!